# Tailwindcss - columns in wrong direction

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a simple flexbox with a column grid of 2.

```html
    <div class="flex relative">
        <div class="columns-2 gap-4 space-y-4">
            <div class="bg-red-500 p-10">1</div>
            <div class="bg-blue-500 p-10 py-14">2</div>
            <div class="bg-orange-500 p-10 py-20">3</div>
            <div class="bg-green-500 p-10">4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is the arrangement of the columns is in the "wrong" direction. The first row contains div1 and div3 but I want it to contain div1 and div2. How can I change the direction?
[image]

I want the divs to align like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not using the grid of `tailwind-css` !! to use change the `columns:2` to  `grid grid-cols-2`

```
 <div class="flex relative">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 space-y-4">  grid grid-cols-2
            <div class="bg-red-500 p-10">1</div>
            <div class="bg-blue-500 p-10 py-14">2</div>
            <div class="bg-orange-500 p-10 py-20">3</div>
            <div class="bg-green-500 p-10">4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now you can see the `div1` and `div2` are placed in the same row.

---

##### Edit:

But this will position the div but the grid looks similar. How to overcome this ?

Use the following code:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-5 gap-4">
  <div class="row-span-2 flex h-64 items-center justify-center bg-red-500 text-5xl">1</div>
  <div class="row-span-3 flex items-center justify-center bg-blue-500 text-5xl">2</div>
  <div class="row-span-2 flex items-center justify-center bg-orange-500 text-5xl">3</div>
  <div class="row-span-2 flex items-center justify-center bg-green-500 text-5xl">4</div>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

##### [Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/PYTpuUmFyP)

Comment: But now the height of the divs is even and I dont want that

Comment: Yes I see that, I have updated my post according to your layout, now the divs are positioned properly and the divs are uneven, hope it works for you !

Comment: Make tweaks according to your needs, add your desired height

Comment: But I want the divs to have an individual height to their content. So if div1 has e.g. 200 words it should be larger than div2 with 50 words. You know what I mean?

Comment: No I couldn't get you ! pardon me. Could you explain it further? Do you want the elements to have height of their contents? And not Spanning?

Comment: I edit the post to how I want it to look without a fixed height or height class (:

Comment: Based on what are you saying it is larger smaller ? It needs a criteria  Is it contents? or random? or specific ? is these divs height static ? or does it change according to some reference ? if yess what is the reference ? To answer to your question I need to totally understand what you are trying to acheive, and where you are facing problem

Comment: If you dont want this with fixed height. You need to specify the criteria based on which it is spacing that way !